# Printing unicode chars?

Tags: unicode, encoding, printing

Is there a solution to printing unicode characters from `gvim`?

See this:

[image]

Results in this print result

[image]

(Using a Linux setup and Vim 8.0.)

Comment: It looks like your printing setup expects a different character set, or doesn't support unicode at all

Comment: What do you get from `:set enc? fenc? penc?` (as one command)

Comment: In the example above, where I did not save to a file, I get: `encoding=utf-8` `fileencoding=` `printencoding=`

Comment: If I execute `set penc=utf8` the problem in the printed output persists.

Answer (score 4):

Send the buffer to the browser by converting to HTML, then print from there:

```
:TOhtml | w | !open -a Safari %
```

For example I have this in vim:
[image]

If I type

```
:ha
```

I get this:
[image]

But when I send it to the browser I get this (with color scheme!):

[image]

I have this in my .vimrc, which deletes the new html buffer and stored file:

```
nnoremap <F2> <ESC> :TOhtml <bar> w <bar> !open -a Safari % <CR> <bar> ZQ <CR> <bar> execute '!rm %:p.html' <CR>
```

Answer (score 2):

Per this Stackoverflow:4586628 Q/A, [How do you pipe a vim buffer through lpr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586628/how-do-you-pipe-a-vim-buffer-through-lpr/4586667#4586667), I have this entry in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
nmap PpP :%w !lpr -o lpi=8 -o cpi=14<CR><CR>
```

that replaces my old entry,

```
nmap PpP :ha<CR>
```

(`:ha` = `:hardcopy`).

Using `:ha`, Neovim was not printing Greek letters, ... even though my (Arch Linux) `locale` was

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
...
```

and I have this line, near the top of my `~/.vimrc`,

```
scriptencoding utf-8
```

[*Printing is system-dependent, not vim-dependent.*]

I added the `lpi` (lines-per-inch) and `cpi` (characters-per-inch) to jiggle my font size to that similar to as what I was getting with the `:ha` command (I measured/counted with an actual ruler), and run it as a `PpP` command/shortcut, added to my `~/.vimrc`, whenever I want to print the current buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Vim seems to produce fairly simple PostScript through the `:hardcopy` command. PostScript itself has no understanding of Unicode, and so having it render "special characters" properly is a complicated process involving intimate knowledge of fonts, etc.

I filed a bug about this, FWIW: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/8935

I the meantime, I think the best solution is to use an external program to produce your printable output. For instance `paps` ([link](https://github.com/dov/paps)) converts UTF-8 text to PostScript. You can, of course, run this external program from inside Vim using your own command, as described in another answer.